# How can a user change tabs without directly tapping the tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I've been having a very tricky bug where after a significant amount of time on the device and simulator (it's unclear when), tapping anywhere on the screen brings me back to the very first/top tab in the tab bar's tabs. The rough layout for the app is below:

[image: schematic of the app]

For the first/top tab, the user is taken through three scenes, and after completing the third the last two are popped off and the user is returned to the root Scene (the first in the Navigation Controller's stack). I can confirm that there are no memory leaks, at least regarding these controllers. The latter two are popped off and are clearly de-allocated.

In the second/middle tab, the controller holds a container view that holds a UIPageViewController with several controllers.

The third tab is the most straightforward and is a TableViewController with a single detail view.

All three tabs in some way reference the base tab bar controller, which is where I have put a common store object that each of the tabs may read/write to.

It does not make sense in the app to press the first tab to clear the cyclic Scene, so I have implemented a check in the base UITabBarController that blocks against clearing it when already at that tab and returning `true` otherwise:

```
func tabBarController(
        _ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController
    ) -> Bool {
        guard let vc = selectedViewController else {
            fatalError(
                "TabBarController should always have a non-nil selectedViewController.")
        }
        var result = true

        if let currentVC = vc as? UINavigationController {
            // Block clearing to the base Controller in the Cycle if already in the Cycle.
            if let cvc = currentVC.viewControllers[0] as? CyclicViewController
            {
                let areEqual = viewController.isEqual(currentVC as UIViewController)
                result = !areEqual
            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

As stated, after a certain amount of time (usually after at least one or two iterations of the cyclic View Controllers in the first tab, although sometimes at launch as well), the app eventually and permanently starts to return to the the first tab when tapping the screen, regardless of which controller or where you tap. You can still tap back to the other tabs, but tapping anywhere brings you back to the first, even when tapping on the current tab. It's like the first tab hasn't really been switched out, even though it clearly does as the above method is called.

I can confirm that the above `shouldSelect` is called with these unintentional tab switches, but this is the only code that ever talks about switching between tabs. Nowhere else in the codebase is there code that says to switch to another tab, conditionally or otherwise.

There is no threaded code anywhere in my codebase. Everything runs on the main thread.

The `selectedViewController` property is assigned to the View Controller at first/top tab in the `viewDidLoad` of the Tab Bar Controller.

I would like to be able to reproduce this, but can't seem to, or else I'd have used a simpler example. I'm aware I'm not showing much, but I'd rather not show more than what I have. Setting break points is a huge pain, even with a generous limit - I don't know how to reliably reproduce this error, so it's very difficult to put a number and the breakpoint is very annoying to use.

Regarding tap gesture recognizers - the middle tab with its PageViewController does page through several ViewControllers with objects that have tap gesture recognizers. I can confirm with `grep -R "ecognizer"` in my workspace that I have zero tap gesture recognizers myself. Crucially, the issue affects the third tab too, which never uses tap gesture recognizers.

I am going slightly insane looking at this, so anyone that can clarify why tabs might be switching despite very clearly not tapping another tab would be hugely appreciated.

For specs, I am running on a MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina), with Xcode 12.4 and running iOS 14.1 on an iPhone SE 2nd Gen and iPhone 12 (both simulated) and an iPhone 7 (real).

Comment: "Setting break points is a huge pain, even with a generous limit" Use _configured_ breakpoints. This will allow you to hit the breakpoint but automatically continue. In the meantime the breakpoint also logs (because that's how you've configured it). In this way you painlessly insert a whole lot of logging and can track what's going on better. — Also, don't forget the view debugger. If you can just manage to get yourself into this situation, the view debugger might just give you some idea what's doing on. Something you can't see directly might be interfering in the story.

Comment: Another random thought, maybe irrelevant: Your `areEqual` is really weird. Why are you not using the `!==` operator?

Comment: Final thought: the fact that merely tapping causes an interface change suggests that you've got a tap gesture recognizer that you're installing at some point. Of course you did not show that, but how could mere tapping have _any_ effect otherwise?

Comment: @matt, I didn't realise there was a `!==` operator, so I've added that now. I doubt that makes any difference though.

Comment: @matt, I've clarified the tap gesture recognizers point above.